# Checking if a number is an integer in C++

Tags: c++, integer

I am searching for a way to check if a certain variable holds an integer or no. My program asks the user for the values of a set of variable then it computes the variable k needed to make another variable e an integer. The code for calculating k is essentially a for loop that increments k from zero until it reaches a value making e an integer. But I can't figure out how to check that e is an integer. Here is the code I am thinking of:

```
for (int k = 0; k!=wk; k++) 
 { 
  e = (1+k*f_n)/d;
 if()
 }
```

The variable wk is just there so that when e is an integer, wk is to be equal to k, and so the loop ends.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That question contains answers for the `r` language

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the other question isn't c++

Comment: Compare the value of `(int)e` with `e` and make sure they are equal...

Comment: What was e declared as?

Comment: @gha.st Sorry, that was too quick voting! But I'm pretty sure there's an appropriate dupe for c++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to check if `e` is an integer. You want to check if `1 + k*f_n` is a multiple of `d`. Use the modulo operator for that.

```
if (((1 + k*f_n) % d) == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `e` is a floating-point type,

```
int u = (int) e;
if (e > (float)u || e < (float)u)
  continue;
break;
```

This solution within the confines of what is otherwise modular arithmetic will suffer from rounding errors.  Please consider using the modulus operator instead.

Comment: This approach is incomplete if e is negative.